# Is hierarchy available in Azure Application Insights (like AWS Cloudwatch)

Tags: azure, logging, sdk, azure-application-insights, azure-rest-api

Can we create directory in application insights? Like Aws Cloudwatch has `Log Groups` inside that log streams can we apply same structure in Azure Application Insights?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417656/application-insights-and-tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over the docs for Cloudwatch it doesn't look like there's a direct correlation between App Insights and Cloudwatch, but you can get a similar effect.

Azure also has the concept of tagging, and that can be applied to any resource or resource group.

For the data retention settings, you can't automatically sync them between App Insights instances, but the recommended structure is to use a single App Insights instance for all the components in an application and they will be divided by cloud_RoleName property. By that architecture App Insights instance would be at least somewhat equivalent to a group and the RoleName would designate a specific stream.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to set cloud role name by spring.application.name ="cloudRoleName" while pushing telemetry. It worked .But can we create cloud rolename from azure application insights dashboard ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a role name before you start using it? When you start sending a new role in your telemetry the list in the portal will automatically add it.