# Azure API Management - custom trace in Application Insight

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a trace policy in my API and I want to read the content of the trace into Application Insight. App Insight is associated with my APIM instance because I can see all traces into AppInsight.

I can see that a "trace" record is added to Application Insight. But what I'm looking for is the ability to add a custom property into the "Request" trace. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adding new properties to existing request is possible using [`ITelemetryInitializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) as mentioned here.

```
var request = new RequestTelemetry();
request.Name = "My Request";
request.Context.Properties["User_Name"] = userName;
request.Context.Properties["Tenant_Code"] = tenantCode;
var client = new TelemetryClient();
client.TrackRequest(request);
```

Use telemetry initializers to enrich telemetry with additional information and/or to override telemetry properties set by the standard telemetry modules. Refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036729).