# Adding custom properties for each request in Application Insights metrics (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure-application-insights, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to add custom properties to Application Insights to each request. I'm trying to achieve the same thing as described in this post ([Adding custom properties for each request in Application Insights metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036729/adding-custom-properties-for-each-request-in-application-insights-metrics)) using VB.NET code  .

I converted the suggested solution C# code to VB.NET as follow :

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("LoggedInUserName", "DummyUser");

    }
}
```

and

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new CustomTelemetry());
```

to

```
Imports Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel
Imports Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts
Imports Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility

Public Class CustomTelemetry
    Inherits ITelemetryInitializer

    Public Sub Initialize(ByVal telemetry As ITelemetry)
        Dim requestTelemetry = TryCast(telemetry, RequestTelemetry)
        If requestTelemetry Is Nothing Then Return
        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("TEST", "TESTERRRRRR")
    End Sub

End Class
```

and

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(New CustomTelemetry())
```

However this gives me an error on **Inherits ITelemetryInitializer**

> Classes can inherit only from other classes.

I've also tried to use "Implements" instead of inherits, but still no Custom properties is sent to AI on page visit.

```
Public Class CustomTelemetry
    Implements ITelemetryInitializer

    Public Sub Initialize(ByVal telemetry As ITelemetry)
        Dim requestTelemetry = TryCast(telemetry, RequestTelemetry)
        If requestTelemetry Is Nothing Then Return
        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("TEST", "TESTERRRRRR")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ITelemetryInitializer_Initialize(telemetry As ITelemetry) Implements ITelemetryInitializer.Initialize
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I was wondering what i'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work as follow:

```
Imports Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel
Imports Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts
Imports Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility

Public Class CustomTelemetry
    Implements ITelemetryInitializer

    Private Sub ITelemetryInitializer_Initialize(telemetry As ITelemetry) Implements ITelemetryInitializer.Initialize
        Dim requestTelemetry = CType(telemetry, RequestTelemetry)
        If (requestTelemetry Is Nothing) Then
            Return
        End If

        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("TEST", "TESTERRRRRR")
    End Sub
End Class
```