# Add Custom Properties to Application Insights Request Telemetry in WCF

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get some additional information about the message we received (basically its application-level outcome) into the Application Insights `RequestTelemetry` object for a WCF service.

Application Insights is logging request telemetry already. I created an `ITelemetryInitializer` that is being run, but at the time it runs I have no way that I can find to access information about the request, much less application-specific data from the request's context.

Is there somewhere I can put data that will be accessible by the `ITelemetryInitializer` at the time it runs?

```
    public class WcfServiceTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry rTelemetry)
            {
                // HttpContext.Current is populated at this point, but doesn't seem to be available within my application code.
                // So is System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are the data that you want to add to telemetry? Please provide an example.

Comment: For example, I have basic authentication. From the username in the authorization header I look up a user record in our system. I'd like to store the user's ID in the telemetry.

Also this service is one where if there's an application error it returns a 200 and the error description is in the response text, and I'd like to put the error code in the telemetry if possible.

I was trying something like:
`HttpContext.Current.Items["property"] = "value";`

But `HttpContext.Current` is not available in the application code.

Comment: I also tried adding to `OperationContext.Current.IncomingRequestProperties` which is available from the application, but not from the `TelemetryInitializer`

Comment: I'm sad to say I've given up on this. My solution ended up being to migrate the service to WebAPI which, if I'm being honest, is probably for my long-term sanity anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to face similar issue as the author described. Tried by implementing `ITelemetryInitializer`/`ITelemetryProcessor` but did not work.

Ended up writing my own `MessageTraceTelemetryModule` class implementing `IWcfTelemetryModule` and `IWcfMessageTrace`.

In the `OnTraceResponse` method, I added my custom property to the request telemetry by extracting value from `OperationContext` (*which is accessible here!*):

```cs
internal class MessageTraceTelemetryModule : IWcfTelemetryModule, IWcfMessageTrace
{
    public void OnTraceResponse(IOperationContext operation, ref Message response)
    {
        if (OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.TryGetValue("clientID", out object value))
        {
            operation.Request.Properties.Add("clientID", value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

New custom property visible in Application Insights telemetry - [ClientID custom property Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8WYk.png).
Note that the `clientID` property is being set in the `OperationContext` in Message Inspector:

```cs
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    if(!OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.ContainsKey("clientID"))
        OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Add("clientID", clientID);
}
```

**Brief Context:**

I implemented AAD Token based Authentication in a **SOAP based WCF Service**. 
I needed to store the `clientID` from the token (which is validated in message inspector) and add the same as a `custom property` in the application insights request telemetry.
**References:**

1. [Message Inspectors Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors)
2. [Application Insights for WCF Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/blob/master/WCF/readme.md)

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, Application Insights automatically adds custom dimensions from data you store in `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.AddBaggage()`, or at least it does in asp.net 5. That might be available at the right place for you in WCF land.

e.g.

```
var currentActivity = System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current;
if (currentActivity != null)
{
    currentActivity.AddBaggage("MyPropertyName", someData);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To log custom property, you can try like this...

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("CustomProperty", "DummyValue");
    }
}
```

And register `CustomTelemetry` at start of the application

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new CustomTelemetry());
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036729/adding-custom-properties-for-each-request-in-application-insights-metrics) is the Original Answer

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) - Application Insights API for custom events and metrics

Comment: This does not answer the question. Looks like the OP knows how to add properties but needs a way to access details about the WCF operation to use as values for the custom properties

Comment: Like Peter said, I know how to add the properties. If I just wanted to add a constant value to every request I'd be good, but I'm trying to get some information in there that's not just specific to the request, but specific to how my application handled the request. I was hoping to call `HttpContext.Current.Items` from my application code, but it's null.